# Mongoid save fails silently without embedded_in relation

Tags: mongoid, embed

I have one document embedded in another in Mongoid.

```
class A < B
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :shipping_address, class_name: 'Address'
```

I have, in my case, omitted the inverse relation:

```
class Address
   # embedded_in :A
```

Why is it, that although the API works fine and completely as expected:

```
 address = A.address
 address.zip = 1234

 a.changed? #true

 address.save

 a.changed? #false
```

**The document is not actually saved**?

If i return the `embedded_in` statement, the save actually works fine.

Comment: You do have `include Mongoid::Document` in the Address class as well, right? The example only shows two lines.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of the Mongoid source is not the best so don't kick me too hard mods.

I assume that Mongoid is similar to ActiveRecord in this regard. With ActiveRecord, defining a `:has_many` does not change the parent object but includes methods for accessing the child. `belongs_to` on the other hand pulls methods for managing foreign keys.

Looking at the source code for Mongoid it seems that persistence is called from the embedded class to the parent and not the other way around ([source](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/embedded/insert.rb)). Removing the `embedded_in` would remove the additional methods for inserting the child into the parent.

Feel free to correct me if I am way off :)

Comment: See my comment on @platform's post.  Presumably removing those methods would then make it save as a root document-- but it doesn't.  Or maybe I'm just looking the wrong way.

Comment: If you look at the raw BSON stored in a mongoid `has_and_belongs_to_many` you will see that the class with `has_and_belongs_to_many` in it is storing foreign keys (and often object types). If you really want to get around the embedded_in call you could always force it in. Create a field `:addresses` and store a serialized array of Address in it.

Answer (score 1):

While you can gain a lot when you choose to embed documents in MongoDB, you do give up the ability to query everything outside of the context of the parent. If you want to be able to work with Address documents independently, outside of the context of the parent document, you should link documents with `has_many` instead of embedding with `embeds_many`. This comes with it's own set of pros and cons.

If you choose to embed documents, you do specify `embedded_in` in the model and you access the embedded documents like this:

```
a = A.new     # Parent document
a.addresses   # Embedded Address documents
```

( [Documentation Reference](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html) )

Comment: This is a good start, I think.  But if that were fully the case, removing the `embedded_in`, would then persist to the top level.  But running `Address.count` show's that it does not.  Perhaps an error should be being thrown here..

Comment: It might help if I understood why you are trying to avoid using `embedded_in`? I've never seen any example in Mongoid documentation where they didn't make the relationship mutual.

Comment: There is [this mention](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_and_belongs_to_many) of a one-sided relationship in the docs, but it's a many-to-many referential relationship using `has_and_belongs_to_many`, and not embedded documents.